# can't get recurrence end date using EWS java api

Tags: exchangewebservices, recurrence

I want to get recurrence end date using EWS java api.

EWS java api support method called Recurrence.getEndDate().

But it is not working on my project.

Recurrence class have 4 get `method(getStartDate, getEndDate, getNumberOfOccurences, getClass)`.

I can get startdate and class but the others can't get.

Anyone help me please.

Following code is get recurrence in my project. Thanks:)

```
PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(TaskSchema.Recurrence);

Task task = Task.bind(service,new ItemId(task_id),propSet);

Recurrence rec = task.getRecurrence();

rec.getEndDate();

rec.getNumberOfOccurrences();
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem recently and found out that it is because of a bug in the EWS Java API.

### The Fix

To fix the bug, you need to make changes to the source code in two places in EWS Java API 1.2 (changes are in the comments):

`EndDateRecurrenceRange.java` (line 63)

```
protected void setupRecurrence(Recurrence recurrence) throws Exception {
    super.setupRecurrence(recurrence);
    this.endDate = recurrence.getEndDate(); // remove this line
    recurrence.setEndDate(this.endDate); // add this line
}
```

`NumberedRecurrenceRange.java` (line 61)

```
protected void setupRecurrence(Recurrence recurrence) throws Exception {
    super.setupRecurrence(recurrence);
    this.numberOfOccurrences = recurrence.getNumberOfOccurrences(); // remove this line
    recurrence.setNumberOfOccurrences(this.numberOfOccurrences); // add this line
}
```

### The Explanation

`RecurrencePropertyDefinition` is the class that parses the recurrence out of an EWS XML response. When parsing the XML response, the `RecurrenceRange` classes, such as the ones listed above, are used to setup the recurrence fields specifying when the recurrence ends (e.g. end date, number of occurrences, no end). This is done by calling `setupRecurrence()`.

Unfortunately, in the two places mentioned above, the developers mistakenly set the `RecurrenceRange` fields to the *empty* `Recurrence` fields instead of the other way around. As a result, the `endDate` and `numberOfOccurrences` fields in the returned `Recurrence` object are never set and are therefore always `null`.

Comment: The EWS Java API has recently been put into a GitHub repository by Microsoft themselves:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api

I recently submitted the fix suggested by gloo as a pull request:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/pull/49

and just wanted to acknowledge his good work here!